# selenium webdriver "is_element_present" is the same as "driver.find_element_by~"?

Tags: python, unit-testing, selenium, webdriver

I'm writting tests in unittest webdriver selenium

What's the point of using is_element_present instead of just "find_element_by~" if it contains it already?

```
def is_element_present(self, how, what):
        try: self.driver.find_element(by=how, value=what)
        except NoSuchElementException, e: return False
        return True
```

I mean whenever i use 'is_element_present' it goes through 'find_element_by~' anyway so whats the point of it?

This and this gives me the same exception if occured so whats the difference?

Comment: isElementPresent does not throw exceptions under normal circumstances, just a boolean value. Using findElementBy you have to handle the exceptions. The code you posted hides the NoSuchElementException also - it will simply return false if it catches it.

Comment: @skandigraun you should put your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`isElementPresent` does not throw the same exception as `findElementBy` - at least `NoSuchElementException` is never thrown. The code you pasted hides the `NoSuchElementException` also - it simply returns false.

So this exception has to be handled by you when using `findElementBy`.

Beside the exceptions, the return values are different also. `findElementBy` returns the first matching `WebElement` that you can use later in your code. `isElementPresent` is only a check if the specified element can be found on the page or not, returning a boolean value.